# HTML rendering issue - space between 2 characters

Tags: java, html, jsp, rendering

I have a HTML renderer java file which has the below code and its called from JSP and displays to UI. It comes with an hyperlink as below.

```
sb.append( "<td style=\"white-space:nowrap;\">").append( "<a href=\"" ).append(taxDetailHref).append("\">").append( txVO.getTaxNumber() ).append( txVO.getTaxType() ).append( "</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>" );
```

Here `txVO.getTaxType()` is `"AS"`

When it renderes/displays to UI I see a space between 2 characters of the same field in the form like for example,`"201518712135751AS"` gets displayed as `"201518712135751A S"`
What could be the reason? I removed the hyperlink and tried to display in the UI and it works fine but not with hyperlink. Any pointers?

Comment: If that is truly the code you are using, then `txVO.getTaxType()` must return a string with a space (or some other character) between `A` and `S`

Comment: If it is a simple string you can use `replaceAll()` : `txVO.getTextType().replaceAll("\\s","")`.

Comment: @Sean Bright : y would there be a space between A and S?

Comment: @JNPW: Because based on the code you have provided, there is no other option.

Comment: oh No. It doesnt have a space im sure. its just "AS"

Comment: If I remove the hyperlink and display it works fine.

Comment: View the source of the rendered page in your browser and update your question with what the rendered HTML is.

Comment: Do you have letter-spacing on your `<a>` elements [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/upmfekkm/) ?

Comment: td has a whitespace. <a> doesnt have letter spacing though. this is my td:<td style=\"white-space:nowrap;\">